# WAMP has started to generate SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] errors

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

Hi I'm running Windows 8 64bit, wamp 3.1.3 32bit, Apache 2.4.33, PHP 5.6.35, MySQL 5.7.21, and MariaDB 10.2.14

I'm building a login system and in the last 24 hours I have started to receive an ERROR MESSAGE =

Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-

Query

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+-+-+-+-+-+-+-

I am using WAMP without issue for approx 5 months.  I am using localhost with MySQL on a live (.IE Irish domain).

Until 24 hours ago eEverything worked OK. Now, all attempts from the localhost to connect to MsSQL fail (e.g. to search the DB for a user and verify a password).

However, if I FTP files to my domain the connection is OK and a successful connection is made to the DB.

I have read all other entries around this and similar issues.  It seems quite common and (to the extent that I can understand the other replies) I cannot find a solution:-

So far I have tried:-
- Searching form.wampserver.com, Stackoverflow and youtube.
- I disabled Avast (my antivirus), 
- I checked the c:...host file (it only has 5 lines), 
- I do not think that any system changes have been made to my pc, 
- I have not installed any new software,
- I've tried 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, 
- I've checked to see if port 3306 is available (I think it is but I'm new to this and cannot be sure I have done this correctly).

Below is a sample of a file I created to test the connection:-
(PS I know mysql is depreciated - but this was written only to test the connection!)
(PPS Obviously I've removed the real name/pw/host, etc)

```
<?php

$dbname = 'dbname';
$dbuser = 'username';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbhost = 'dbname';
$connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Unable to 
Connect to '$dbhost'");
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Could not open the db '$dbname'");
$test_query = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";  
$result = mysql_query($test_query);
$tblCnt = 0;
while($tbl = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $tblCnt++;
    #echo $tbl[0]."<br />\n";
}
if (!$tblCnt) {
    echo "There are no tables<br />\n";
    } else {
    echo "There are $tblCnt tables<br />\n";
}
?>
```

Any attempt to connect to MySql from wamp/localhost generates the error.  But if the file is FTP'd to a real domain it successfully connects and prints the number of tables in the DB (which is 6).  Therefore, there are no mistakes in the url/db/username/pwd, and I don't believe there are any changes with PHP/MySQL set up on my domain.

Also as the file works when put on a live server, the username/pw, db, etc are all correctly spelt.

Finally, I have been saving different versions of my website in development.  Each of the last 6 versions have worked without any issue.  Now none of the earlier versions of the login system work.  This means that I can rule out any mistake made in the recent version of the website.

I'm a newbie and I'm stuck.  I hope not to get roasted if this in fact turns out to be a repetition of another question/response.  I have done my best to find an answer before posting this.

Any help would be *Greatly* appreciated...

Comment: "A connection attempt failed…" indicates the MySQL server is down. Show the process list of development (localhost?) and your production systems.

Comment: Thank you Mario for replying.  My first time doing this...after some googling...I logged into MySQLAdmin and ran the SPL command and this is the result:-

Comment: 39 root localhost:49914 NULL Query 0 starting show 
    full PROCESSLIST 
    40 root localhost:49915 NULL Sleep 1  NULL 
 Sorry, but I can't find anything on 'production systems'

Comment: PS...I am querying the MySQL server (which is online) simultaneously and it's working fine...e.g. running the test code above in WAMP generates the error but running live runs OK. So online server has to be OK...right? <stumped>